# Is there a way to define which object keys to use instead of "label" and "value" in the CoreUI's CSelect component for Vue?

Tags: vue.js, core-ui

I'm using CoreUI's CSelect component and, in the documentation is specified that the "options" property must be an array of objects with the "label" and "value" keys.
[CSelect API](https://coreui.io/vue/docs/components/form-components.html#cselect-api)

My question is if is there any property of the CSelect component that allows me to specify which keys to use instead of "label" and "value". This way I wouldn't have to apply the map function on my array.

```
<CSelect
    label="Category"
    :options="categories"
    placeholder="Select Category"
    :value.sync="form.category_id"
    ... // some properties here
/>

// example of data function
data() {
    return {
        categories: [{id:1 , name:"Vue" }, {id:2, name:"Angular"}],
    };
},
```

Thanks in advance. Sorry for my English.

Answer (score -1):

```
[{value:1 , label:"Vue" }, {value:2, label:"Angular"}]
```

This should help you.

Comment: Hello and welcome on SO. To make your answer really helpful, you could add details about how your code/data is helping with the issue, and how.